# Swift regex doesn't work to replace a line

Tags: swift, regex

I have this regex to match a line which contains a specific URL:

```
let pattern_1 = "([\\ ]*)"

// Look for '.package(url: "https://example.com/path",' while taking into account whitespace (incl. newline) in between the colon, double quotes,and comma.
let pattern_2 = "\\.package\\([[:space:]]*url[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*\\\"\(escapedUrl)\"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"

// This is intended to match '(from|branch|revision|exact):' and any of the following:
//    - "1.0.0"
//    - "some/branch/name" or "asd1234zxc678qwe"
let pattern_3 = "(from|branch|revision|exact)[[:space:]]*:[\\ ]*\"[A-z0-9\\.]+\""

// Matches '.upToNextMinor', '.upToNextMajor(' followed with "x.x.x", and ')'
let pattern_4 = "\\.[A-z]+[\\ ]*\\([A-z]+:[\\ ]*\"[0-9\\.]+\"\\)"

// This matches range, such as "0.0.0"..<"1.0.0" or "0.0.0"..."1.0.0"
let pattern_5 = "\"([0-9]+\\.{0,1})+\"\\.{2}(\\.|<)\"([0-9]+\\.{0,1})+\""

// This is to look for the enclosing parentheses or comma, if found. Take into account space and newline before parentheses
let pattern_6 = "[[:space:]]*\\)([,]*)"

// The whole pattern
let pattern = "\(pattern_1)\(pattern_2)(\(pattern_3)|\(pattern_4)|\(pattern_5))\(pattern_6)"
```

Assumed the `escapedUrl` is `https://bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX`, and this is the sample text:

```
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX", .upToNextMinor(from:"1.0.0"))
],
```

Or:

```
dependencies: [
    .package(url: 
        "https://bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX", 
        .upToNextMinor(from:"1.0.0"))
],
```

The regex will need to match the whole line on whatever format it is (include or exclude the enter). Whenever it's match, will need to replace the line with another text. It doesn't work in Swift but it works when I run the regex using a bash script. What's wrong with the regex?

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with enough code to fully reproduce your attempts to use your 6 patterns against your sample text.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me in my tests. The whole line with the `escapedUrl`
 is replaced by some other text.

Comment: A general tip. If you delimit the strings with `#"` .... `"#` you don't need to escape the `\ ` and `"` characters. It makes regexes much easier to read. For example: `let pattern_4 = #"\.[A-z]+[\ ]*\([A-z]+:[\ ]*"[0-9\.]+"\)"#`

Comment: See [Extended String Delimiters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#Extended-String-Delimiters) for a full explanation

Comment: Hey @workingdogsupportUkraine, can you please tell the code you use to replace the text?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tips! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used in my tests.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(results)
            .onAppear {
                
                let escapedUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX"
                
                let pattern_1 = "([\\ ]*)"
                
                // Look for '.package(url: "https://example.com/path",' while taking into account whitespace (incl. newline) in between the colon, double quotes,and comma.
                let pattern_2 = "\\.package\\([[:space:]]*url[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*\\\"\(escapedUrl)\"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"
                
                // This is intended to match '(from|branch|revision|exact):' and any of the following:
                //    - "1.0.0"
                //    - "some/branch/name" or "asd1234zxc678qwe"
                let pattern_3 = "(from|branch|revision|exact)[[:space:]]*:[\\ ]*\"[A-z0-9\\.]+\""
                
                // Matches '.upToNextMinor', '.upToNextMajor(' followed with "x.x.x", and ')'
                let pattern_4 = "\\.[A-z]+[\\ ]*\\([A-z]+:[\\ ]*\"[0-9\\.]+\"\\)"
                
                // This matches range, such as "0.0.0"..<"1.0.0" or "0.0.0"..."1.0.0"
                let pattern_5 = "\"([0-9]+\\.{0,1})+\"\\.{2}(\\.|<)\"([0-9]+\\.{0,1})+\""
                
                // This is to look for the enclosing parentheses or comma, if found. Take into account space and newline before parentheses
                let pattern_6 = "[[:space:]]*\\)([,]*)"
                
                // The whole pattern
                let pattern = "\(pattern_1)\(pattern_2)(\(pattern_3)|\(pattern_4)|\(pattern_5))\(pattern_6)"
                
                let test1 = """
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX", .upToNextMinor(from:"1.0.0"))
],
"""
                
                let test2 = """
dependencies: [
    .package(url:
        "https://bitbucket.org/XXX/XXX",
        .upToNextMinor(from:"1.0.0"))
],
"""
                
                results = test1.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "done", options: [.regularExpression])
                print("\n---> results: \(results) \n")
                
            }
    }
}
```